# While infinite (Restriction) loop is not working properly

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

as one of my first java projects, I want to build a mortgage calc.
I was trying to restrict the duration that the user can pick using this code

```
Scanner numOfPayments = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter number of payments (the number of Years you will be paying the loan):");
    short numOfPayments2 = numOfPayments.nextShort();
    if (numOfPayments2 >= 1 && numOfPayments3 <= 30) {
        numOfPayments3 = (short) (numOfPayments2 * 12);
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter a valid number of years(Between 1 and 30)");
}
```

It worked with restricting other values, but not for this one.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `numOfPayments3 <= 30` => `numOfPayments2 <= 30` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @azro for the answer
I should just change numOfPayments3 to numOfPayments2 inside the If statement